# Creating a div in haml with javascript with a yield tag inside

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm working in my main application layout, a haml page in my Rails app. I'm trying to render one `div` or a slightly different one depending on the value of a property on my Javascript localStorage object. As such, I'm using javascript to create said `div`s and appending them where I need them on the page. However, the divs in question are meant to be containers for other views, and make use of the rails `yield` keyword. How can I add a haml/erb yield to my generated divs? haml:

```
#parent-container
  :javascript
    $(document).ready( function() {
      let parentContainer = document.querySelector("#parent-container")
      let childContainer = document.createElement('div')
      childContainer.setAttribute('id', 'child-container')
      if (localStorage["myCondition"] === "true"){
        childContainer.classList.add('container-fluid')
      } else {
        childContainer.classList.add('container')
      }
      parentContainer.appendChild(childContainer)
    });
```